# NHibernate and MySql Missing column Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

From time to time my web application begins throwing the following errors.

Using NHibernate 4.0.0.4000 and MySql.Data 6.8.3

Stack Trace
[ERROR [(null)] - Message:could not execute query](http://pastebin.ca/3830439)

NHibernate log
[NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter WARN - System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Could not find specified column in results:](http://pastebin.ca/3830438)

Once once of these errors occur it begins to happen frequently until the web application is restart.

It's odd that it only happens to some users and not all.  Also I noticed in this particular log message the values of p4 and p5 should be swapped.

Is this an issue with the query cache?

Does anyone have some insight into why this is happening?

If it helps here is the gnarly query (but I see this error on much simpler queries as well)

```
FunderInfoViewModel funderDto = null;
Funder funderAlias = null;
Contact contactAlias = null;

var totalOpportunitiesAwardedCount = QueryOver.Of<Opportunity>()
                .Where(o => o.Funder.Id == funderAlias.Id)
                .And(o => o.Status == OpportunityStatus.Awarded || o.Status == OpportunityStatus.AwardedClosed)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectCount(o => o.Id));

            var totalOpportunitiesAwardedSum = QueryOver.Of<Opportunity>()
                .Where(o => o.Funder.Id == funderAlias.Id)
                .And(o => o.Status == OpportunityStatus.Awarded || o.Status == OpportunityStatus.AwardedClosed)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectSum(o => o.AmountAwarded));

            var totalOpportunitiesCount = QueryOver.Of<Opportunity>()
                .Where(o => o.Funder.Id == funderAlias.Id)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .SelectCount(o => o.Id));

            IEnumerable<FunderInfoViewModel> funders = _session.QueryOver(() => funderAlias)
                .Left.JoinAlias(f => f.Contacts, () => contactAlias, x => x.IsDefault)
                .Where(o => o.Organization.Id == organizationId)
                .SelectList(list => list
                    .Select(x => x.Id)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.Id)
                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.Name)
                    .Select(x => x.Description)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.Description)
                    .Select(x => x.AreasOfInterest)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.AreasOfInterest)
                    .Select(x => x.Type)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.FunderType)
                    .Select(x => x.TaxId)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.TaxId)
                    .Select(x => x.PhoneNumber)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.PhoneNumber)
                    .Select(x => x.FaxNumber)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.FaxNumber)
                    .Select(x => x.EmailAddress)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.EmailAddress)
                    .Select(x => x.Website)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.Website)
                    .Select(x => x.CustomLink)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.CustomLink)
                    .Select(x => x.MinimumFundingRange)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.MinimumFundingRange)
                    .Select(x => x.MaximumFundingRange)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.MaximumFundingRange)
                    .Select(() => contactAlias.FirstName)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.PrimaryContactFirstName)
                    .Select(() => contactAlias.LastName)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.PrimaryContactLastName)
                    .Select(() => contactAlias.Title)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.PrimaryContactTitle)
                    .SelectSubQuery(totalOpportunitiesAwardedCount)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.AwardedOpportunitiesCount)
                    .SelectSubQuery(totalOpportunitiesAwardedSum)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.AwardedOpportunitiesValue)
                    .SelectSubQuery(totalOpportunitiesCount)
                    .WithAlias(() => funderDto.OpportunitiesCount)
                )
                .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
                .Asc
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<FunderInfoViewModel>())
                .List<FunderInfoViewModel>();
```

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet? Then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the problem. Its because some of the arguement you are passing in your prepared statement is null, thats why this error. I had similar issue earlier and i solved it by checking only if it is not null add it in query filtering.

Also there is another possibility of row lock by any other query. Are you using lock in mysql query?

2nd problem seems like see the solution stated below

https://forums.asp.net/t/1230295.aspx?IDataReader+Could+not+find+specified+column+in+results+

Comment: Nothing is null in the query.  I send in several constants and based on the logged query the one dynamic value is attached as a parameter.